# Is wiping of the nose with hand or cloth permitted during prayers?

Tags: salat, fiqh

Sometimes, when I pray, I feel so overcome with gratitude and love for the One that created, clothed, sustained and thought me everything I know that I end up shedding tears in prostration. This eventually leads to my nose dripping uncontrollably.

I understand that moving around too much during prayer is not allowed. Would my prayer be nullified if I wiped my nose multiple times during prayer?

Also, there are times when I don't have a tissue handy to wipe my nose. I have no choice but to wipe it on my hands or clothes. Is this considered najis?

If so, what else can I do? I'm only human and there will be times when I will forget to have a tissue in my pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excessive movement, which is not part of Salah will nullify Salah except for making necessary movements when needed such as: wiping the nose, scratching, etc.

And it is not najis.

---

**Reference:**

Taqlid Marja Tauzeeh-ul-Masail.for example:

[en.wikipedia.org/Tauzeeh-ul-Masail_Ayatollah_al-Uzma_Seyyid_Ali_al-Sistani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauzeeh-ul-Masail_%28Ayatollah_al-Uzma_Seyyid_Ali_al-Sistani%29)